# How can you make that tables in your Joomla articles are responsive and re-size appropriately with screen size?

Tags: joomla-3.x

How can you make that in Joomla, for example for the visibility of a table of a Joomla article on a mobile phone ?

Comment: Tables are usually not best practice for responsive layout and most Joomla templates include Bootstrap or similar so you can implement a responsive grid with appropriate CSS classes instead of tables.

Comment: Not a actually a Joomla question - as per how do it: Google "html/css responsive tables", or check "bootstrap responsive tables" and you will get many ideas.

Comment: _Must Reads_: https://www.lifewire.com/dont-use-tables-for-layout-3468941 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/83073/2943403

Comment: Please edit your question to provide some sample html (for context) and show us a screenshpt of how it is not being displayed properly on a mobile device.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
    table style="height: 100%; width: 100%;"border="1"
```

into the html code actually perfectly did it, all tables perfectly responsive now.

Comment: I think it would be appropriate for you to paste an example of your HTML code here Joe. My experience is that responsive tables do not mean perfection on smaller devices with tables not always resizing as one would like. I have not tried for some time and would be interested in what you have done that would be comparable to bootstrap responsive grids.

Comment: Just add the part above (table style=...) and the percentages of the screen you want the table to occupy into the joomla article editor of the beginning tag of each table you use, that's all I did. And it works far better than any of these responsive table plugins or modules available for free for Joomla...

Comment: This is a perfect solution for displaying a few narrow columns but tables don't work particularly well on narrow screens for anything wider.

Comment: Perfectly responsive? No. Full-width, yes, but when content exceeds available screen width the table will overflow and break out; the opposite of responsive.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a Joomla question. Html tables are not responsive, and never will be. If you need to display tabular data in a truly responsive way you will have to fake it and make something that *looks* like a table, but semantically isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Use "Tiny MCE" or "JCE Editor" to create tables. And make "width=100%" in table properties after you fill all the data in table. This will work in most of the responsive templates. Please refer this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HIvORqkUe7w

If it is not working, try some plugins in JED like this: https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/responsive-tables/

Good Luck!